# Saving headings, subheadings, paragraphs and table data in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

I am planning to have views that include a lot of user contributed text in the form of headings, subheadings, paragraphs and table data. Right now I have separate models for headings, subheadings and paragraphs with appropriate belongs_to and has_many relationships. It seems to me that a more ideal solution to saving this user data is out there. I am looking for another tool to effectively save this information in the database.

Thanks so much for any help.

```
class Fly < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :headings
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :headings, allow_destroy: true
end

class Heading < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :fly
    has_many :subheadings
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subheadings, allow_destroy: true
end

class Subheading < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :heading
    has_many :paragraphs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :paragraphs, allow_destroy: true
end

class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subheading
end
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by messy and nonideal?  Is it slow? Is it not helpful in the view abstraction? Also can you actually show us the models and their associations?

Comment: To me it seems messy and non ideal because saving user content in heading/paragraph/table form, to me, seems like such a common occurrence. I am not sure the creating separate models is the ideal approach. Will edit in the models and associations.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am looking for another tool to effectively save this information in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your content stored as something like Textile or Markdown. Instead of having a big tree of headings and subheadings, all you need is a single record per document. The headings, subheadings and paragraphs are contained within the Textile or Markdown.

In your document record, you would store the Textile or Markdown content and whatever metadata you care about.

There are plenty of engines for both Textile and Markdown that will compile to html. When it comes time to display your content, all you need to do is give it to the engine and output the html it gives back to you.

If you want your users to write the content, you can either make them write Markdown or Textile directly or have some kind of wysiwyg tool that generates Textile or Markdown.

Textile and Markdown are both very simple languages. It should be pretty easy for users to pick it up.

I did a quick google search, and it looks like wysiwyg editors for both Markdown and Textile do exist.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

Try using [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) are ready-for-use HTML text editor designed to simplify web                                                                                                            content creation. It's a WYSIWYG editor that brings common word processor features directly to your web pages.

> To integrate them with rails application use these gems [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)
>   or [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your models' complexity simply reflects the structure of content that is like a document. If you want to query about heading, subheading, paragraph and table parts of content then you have to have models/tables distiguishing between and recording those parts. (In fact what you've given is not even sufficiently complex for a minimal heading-subheading-paragraph model. Eg the paragraphs under a heading and the subheadings under a heading each have an associated ordinal position.)

Even if you use a non-relational form for your content, if you want to make those distinctions between parts then the interface operators and managed state have to reflect that structure. 
Remember that "documents" in the sense of XML, HTML, Word or noSQL are generic. If your application has a particular structure of headings, subheadings, paragraphs and tables then you are going to have to describe that structure via a framework of declarations just as "messy" but in a different syntax.

Each relational model/table has an associated parameterized statement. Eg "paragraph #[no] of heading [heading] has paragraph text [text]". A model/table holds the records/rows that form a true statement when field/column values are substituted for parameter names. Eg record/row < no 7, heading '5.1', text '...' > gives "paragraph #7 of heading '5.1' has text '...' ". The only non-application-specific structure in a relational database is its models/tables, whose contents enumerate the facts describing an application.

I can't suggest a gem to leverage prior work. But schema examples are out there. [Eg these documents with section titles, section texts and images.](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/document_management/index.htm)